# How to solve "product does not contain the mandatory attribute 'version'. Please ensure you entered a version in the product file"

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, tycho

I am facing the below error after upgrade my project to tycho 1.0.0. Earlier it was working fine. The error:

> the product does not contain the mandatory attribute 'version'. Please ensure you entered a version in the product file.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: please share the contents of the product file, especially the section where you have mentioned the version.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

add version tag to the product file